# Dispatch multiple action from one effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Hi I want dispatch my new action "LoadConfig" in "loadFullService$" effect.

How to do ?

```
    @Effect()
loadFullService$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<servicesActions.LoadFullService>(servicesActions.LOAD_FULL_SERVICE)
    .switchMap(action => {
        return this.apiService
            .loadFullService(action.payload)
            .map((service: Service) => new servicesActions.LoadFullServiceSuccess(service))
            .catch(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadFailureAction(error)));
    })
    ;

@Effect()
loadConfig$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<servicesActions.LoadConfig>(servicesActions.LOAD_CONFIG)
    .switchMap(action => {
        console.log("action config", action);
        return this.apiService
            .loadConfig(action.id, action.name)
            .map((config: Configuration) => new servicesActions.LoadConfigSuccess(config))
            .catch(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadConfigFailure(error)));
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the Store service in the constructor.

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<StoreType>,
)
```

Then inside the action call `this.store.dispatch(newAction)`, with a `do` operator (usual), anywhere after the `ofType()`.

```js
@Effect()
loadFullService$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<servicesActions.LoadFullService>(servicesActions.LOAD_FULL_SERVICE)
  .do(action => {
    this.store.dispatch(new servicesActions.LoadConfig(action.payload.id, action.payload.name))
  })
  .switchMap(action => {
    return this.apiService
      .loadFullService(action.payload)
      .map((service: Service) => new servicesActions.LoadFullServiceSuccess(service))
      .catch(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadFailureAction(error)));
  });
```

Another general approach, which I used to like, is creating a new observable:

```js
@Effect()
loadFullService$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<servicesActions.LoadFullService>(servicesActions.LOAD_FULL_SERVICE)
  .switchMap(action => {
    return this.apiService
      .loadFullService(action.payload)
      .mergeMap((service: Service) => {
        return new Observable(observer => {
          const successAction = new servicesActions.LoadFullServiceSuccess(service));
          const newAction = new servicesActions.LoadConfig(action.id, successAction.name));
          observer.next(successAction);
          observer.next(newAction);
          observer.complete();
      });
    })
    .catch(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadFailureAction(error)));
});
```

The downside is that it adds more churn and following the code gets a bit harder sometimes.

Finally, a third approach:

```js
@Effect()
loadFullService$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType<servicesActions.LoadFullService>(servicesActions.LOAD_FULL_SERVICE)
  .switchMap(action => {
    return this.apiService
      .loadFullService(action.payload)
      .mergeMap((service: Service) => {
        const successAction = new servicesActions.LoadFullServiceSuccess(service));
        const newAction = new servicesActions.LoadConfig(action.id, successAction.name));
        return Observable.from([successAction, newAction]);
      })
      .catch(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadFailureAction(error)));
  });
```

Comment: I tried but what should I do in the effect? Do a .do (this.store.dispatch (new servicesActions.LoadConfig (action.id, action.name)))?

Comment: Thx u ! Last question i need "name" which is a return value of the "LoadFullService" action, can I get it back?

Comment: `action.payload.name` is from LoadFullService. Or do you mean LoadFullServiceSuccess?

Comment: it may be at `action.name` instead, given you're using classes.

Comment: I meant LoadFullServiceSuccess

Comment: you can run this dispatch anywhere you want (usually on a .do operator), so just move the .do to after the call to LoadFullServiceSuccess. I'll update the answer with another approach for completeness, given you want to dispatch 2 actions at the same time.

Comment: THANK YOU ! You are my saviour ! Thx again !

Answer (score 0):

Effects aren't functions that take one element. They are stream transformations, and you can use all the power of RxJS here. For example, to get what you asked for in the title:

```
@Effect()
loadConfig$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<servicesActions.LoadConfig>(servicesActions.LOAD_CONFIG)
    .switchMap(action => Observable.of(
        new OtherAction(),
        new OtherAction2(),
    );
```

Note: this is quite similar to 3rd version in the André's answer.